# ADF - get Oracle stored procedure output

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can I use the output of an Oracle stored procedure in ADF Copy activity?

I have a code like this, and I need to get OUT_SP into a staging table in Azure SQL instance.

```
DECLARE
  INPUT_DATE DATE;
  OUT_SP SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  INPUT_DATE := '30-Jun-2023';  

  SP(
    INPUT_DATE => INPUT_DATE,
    OUT_SP => OUT_SP
  );
 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Copy" activity option to select stored procedure may not exist for Oracle table dataset.

Like the same way it exists for an Azure SQL database, however there is another approach.

The below steps will help you use a store Procedure in ADF

**Step 1:** In the Copy Activity "Use query" option where you can select "table" or "query".

**Step 2:** when you select "query" there is a space to write your own query statement.

**Step 3:** In this space you can try writing an execute stored procedure statement here.

Know more about the [Copy data from and to Oracle by using Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle?tabs=data-factory)